# Selecting a single test with Cucumber JUnit5 engine fails

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-junit

Consider this simple project: https://github.com/ekalin/cucumber-junit5-gradle. It contains a Cucumber feature, using JUnit5.

Following the instruction from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine, I’ve created a class anotated with `@Cucumber` so that tests can be discovered. And when I run `./gradlew test`, the feature is discovered and run.

But if I try to select only that test with `./gradlew test --tests cucumber.junit5.gradle.SampleSteps` (or with other ways to select the test), I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [cucumber.junit5.gradle.SampleSteps](--tests filter)
```

I’ve tried adding `includeEngines("cucumber")` to `useJUnitPlatform` but it didn’t make any difference.

Is there some configuration to allow selecting a single test when it’s using a different engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle does not yet support discovery or filtering of non-class based tests (see: [gradle/#4773](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4773)). Instead Gradle asks the JUnit Platform to discover tests in all classes in the test package. The `@Cucumber` annotation is a work around to discover all feature files in the package of the annotated class.

When you use `--tests cucumber.junit5.gradle.SampleSteps` you apply a class based filter on all test results. Because the `@Cucumber` annotated class is a work around it is not part of the discovered tests and because feature files do not have a `ClassSource` but rather a `FileSource` gradle will exclude them all.

The best thing you can currently do is use the work around suggested in gradle/#4773. You may also want to request the Gradle team to provide a better integration with the JUnit Platform so all its feature can be used.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this solution, hopefully there'll be a better solution in the future.